# How to specify working directory for github actions for monorepo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Recently I switched from multiple repositories to a monorepo, and I am trying to rewrite my workflows to work with the monorepo. I want to specify path to my subproject for the jobs. For example I have the following job.

```
- name: Gradle Build
      uses: eskatos/gradle-command-action@v1
      with:
        arguments: build test --stacktrace --info
```

How do I make this run from a specific subdirectory?
(or, if possible, I want to specify a base directory for all jobs in the file)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Nicolas G.** answer is correct and would work, but as you explained you wanted to *specify a working directory for all jobs in the file*, the `defaults` field is also valid at the workflow level, **to avoid repetition**.

#### At the workflow level

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./your_working_dir
jobs:
  job1:
    [...]
  job2:
    [...]
```

#### At the job level

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./your_working_dir1
    steps:
    [...]

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./your_working_dir2
    steps:
    [...]
```

You can learn more about the `defaults` field on the [Github official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaults).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But will this work without `run` command ? In the example don't use `run` .

Comment: It works only for `run` commands. Action (`uses`) generally has **inputs** to ask for specific paths when needed. For example here for the gradle command action, it seems to be the `build-root-directory` argument: https://github.community/t/use-gradle-command-on-a-directory-in-a-different-repository/17852

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a **working-directory** for a step or an entire job: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: [base-directory]

    steps:
      - name: step1
        run: [cmd]
        working-directory: ./dir1

    - name: step2
        run: [cmd]
        working-directory: ./dir2
```

You could have a look on this post: https://github.community/t/use-working-directory-for-entire-job/16747

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But will this work without run command ? In the example don't use run .

Comment: Same answer than **GuiFalourd**'s one. Thanks to him :)